# Keras custom loss: a * MAE + (1-a) * constant

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to implement a fairly simple custom loss function in Keras.

I am trying to make the network predict a bad input case (i.e. on which it has no chance of predicting correct output), along with correct output. To try to do this, I used a loss function which allows the network to 'choose' a constant loss (8) instead of it's current loss (determined by MAE).

```
 loss = quality * output + (1-quality) * 8
```

Where quality is output from sigmoid, so in [0,1]

How would I  design such a loss function properly in Keras?

Specifically, in the basic case, the network gets several predictions of the output, along with metrics known or thought to correlate with prediction quality. The role of the (small) network is to use these metrics to determine the weights to give when averaging these different prediction. This works well enough.

However, in some fraction of cases (say 5-10%) the input data is so bad that all predictors will be wrong. In that case, I want to output '?' to the user instead of a wrong answer.

My code complained about 1 array vs 2 arrays (presumably, identical number of y_true and y_pred are expected, but I don't have these).

```
model = Model(inputs=[ain, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, x], outputs=[pred,qual])
model.compile(loss=quality_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit([acc, hrmet0, hrmet1, hrmet2, hrmet3, hrmet4, hrs], ref, epochs=50, batch_size=5000, verbose=2, shuffle=True)
```

It seems having two outputs is causing the loss function to be called independently for each output.

```
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you
are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2
array(s), but instead got the following list of 1 arrays:
```

This was solved by passing a concatenated array instead.

```
def quality_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  qual = y_pred[:,0]
  hr   = y_pred[:,1]
  const = 8

  return qual * mean_absolute_error(y_true,hr) + (1 - qual) * const

def my_mae(y_true,y_pred):
  return  mean_absolute_error(y_true,y_pred[:,1])

model = Model(inputs=[xin, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, hr],     outputs=concatenate([qual, pred_hr]))
model.compile(loss=quality_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=[my_mae])
```

Network code:

```
xin = Input(shape=(1,))

in1 = Input(shape=(4,))
net1 = Dense(3,activation='tanh')( Dense(6,activation='tanh')(in1) )
in2 = Input(shape=(4,))
net2 = Dense(3,activation='tanh')( Dense(6,activation='tanh')(in2) )
in3 = Input(shape=(4,))
net3 = Dense(3,activation='tanh')( Dense(6,activation='tanh')(in3) )
in4 = Input(shape=(4,))
net4 = Dense(3,activation='tanh')( Dense(6,activation='tanh')(in4) )
in5 = Input(shape=(4,))
net5 = Dense(3,activation='tanh')( Dense(6,activation='tanh')(in5) )

smweights = Dense(5, activation='softmax')( concatenate([xin, net1, net2, net3, net4, net5]) ) 
qual = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')( Dense(3, activation='tanh')( concatenate([xin, net1, net2, net3, net4, net5]) ) ) 

x = Input(shape=(5,))
pred = dot([x, smweights], axes=1)
```

This runs, but converges to loss = const and mae > 25 (whereas a simple mae loss here achieves 3-4 quite easily). Something is still not quite right with the loss function. Since shape on y_true/y_pred in the loss function gives (?) it's hard to track what is being passed exactly.

Comment: Please add a minimal version of your network's code, too.

Comment: added as suggested

Answer (score 2):

This issue is actually not caused by your custom loss function, but by something else: The problem arises because of how you call the fit function.
When you define the model, you give it `7` inputs and `2` outputs:

```
model = Model(inputs=[ain, in1, in2, in3, in4, in5, x], outputs=[pred,qual])
```

When you eventually call the `fit` function, you give a list `7` arrays as the input of the network but only `1` target output value called `ref`:

```
model.fit([acc, hrmet0, hrmet1, hrmet2, hrmet3, hrmet4, hrs], ref, ...)
```

This will not work. You have to supply the `fit` function with the same number of inputs and outputs as declared in the model's definition.

Edit: I think there is some conceptual problem with your approach: how are you actually planning to define the quality of your prediction? Why are you thinking, that adding a branch of your network which is supposed to judge the quality of your network's prediction will actually help to train it? The network will converge to a local minimum of the loss function. The fancier your loss function is, the more likely it is, that it will not actually converge to the state you actually want it to be in, but to some other local and not global minimum. You could try to experiment with different optimizers and learning rates - maybe this helps your training.

Comment: I guess the problem arises from not knowing what Keras does with the arguments to Model() and model.fit(). In my naive assumption, this is what the loss function gets (which, as currently implemented expects 2 y_pred but only 1 y_true).
Changing ref to [ref,ref] and y_true to y_true[0] and ['mae'] to a custom MAE function does make it run though, though output is a bit suspect.

Comment: @Sander Please mark this response as the answer to your question, so that other user might profit more from it.

Comment: It's not clear what 2 ytrue you would pass, and it seems the loss function is called independently on both outputs. The actual question remains unanswered.

Comment: @Sander Added and edit, too. Maybe you can try to explain a little bit more, why and what you are planning to do.

Comment: Rewrote my post, hopefully it's clearer. The reason I want both outputs is that this is how the algorithm works, and I expect the same metrics to be relevant to both the prediction of weights, as well as the quality of the prediction. I also hoped it helps training by decreasing focus on reducing the (impossible) worst case, and improving predictions in the case where a reasonable answer exists.